# How to change sort of the clones in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

These clones are created by script.
If I want to change the sort of them(in the hierachy), what should I do? I tried to print the pos but it turned out to be the pososition of the prefab not the clone, which means all these clones share same name and position.

[image]

Really need help.Thanks a lot.

Comment: You want to sort them based on position or you just want to name them from 1 to something?

Comment: Are you trying to achive a "List" in a scrollRect? I know how to do this, and where is the prefab is instantiated?

Answer (score 4):

To get the index of a GameObject in its parent hierarchy and change its position, you can use the [GetSiblingIndex](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetSiblingIndex.html) and [SetSiblingIndex](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetSiblingIndex.html) function of the transform component of your child. The first one will give you the index corresponding to the position of a specific child in the parent's hierarchy, while the second will allow you to place it at a specific index.

The following example will for instance print the index of all the children elements, so from 0 to numberChild - 1 :

```
void Start()
{
    Transform parentTransform = Parent.transform;
    int numberChildren = parentTransform.childCount;

    for(int i = 0; i < numberChildren; i++)
    {
        int index = parentTransform.GetChild(i).GetSiblingIndex();

        Debug.Log(index);
    }
}
```

It's up to you to decide how you will use the SetSiblingIndex function to reorder your elements for your game's purposes.

As side notes: you can change the name of a GameObject by using the [name](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-name.html) component of a GameObject. It can be quite handy if you want to identify quickly all your children:

```
Parent.transform.GetChild(i).name = "Item1";
```

Also, if you're thinking about using the transform component of your Parent object often, store the reference in your class.